# SQL column subquery depending on different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

So I have this database which have to integrate data from x different databases, and I need to make this dynamic query depending on the database the data will come from.

They are a lot of copy pasted bases that have the same structures but different databases. Imagine that you have BaseA, BaseB and BaseC, and they all have the same table named Clients.

For the integration I've created another database named "Integration", and a single table (JoinedClients) that have a column named BaseName, and another one ClientId, and for each register this column will have the data: 'BaseA', 'BaseB' or 'BaseC', ClientId 1, 2 or 3.
Eg.

In BaseA -> Select ClientName From Clients Where ClientId = 1 == McDonald's

In BaseB -> Select ClientName From Clients Where ClientId = 1 == BurguerKing

I'm guessing if I can make some query that I can have the client name depending on the database name.

My select was something like the code below, but SQL didn't follow me... Or I didn't follow him.

Any thoughts?

Danke!

```
USE Integration
GO
SELECT  Id
,       BaseName
,       ClientId
,       (sp_executesql 'Select ClientName From ' + BaseName + '.dbo.Clients Where ClientId = ' + ClientId) As 'ClientName'
FROM JoinedClients
```

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like the problem is the design, not the query; why do you have these as different databases when you need to be able to do (effectively) parametrised queries against them? It seems that what you should like have is a single database and then a column to denote what ever information that database's name is implying.

Comment: The only ways you could do this would be o use `CASE` expressions or `LEFT JOIN`s to reference all the databases, which won't scale, or use completely dynamic SQL, which would scale but would be *awful* to be compelled to always write in when you need to use multiple databases. Fixing the design would make things trivial.

Comment: Legacy my brother! We need to deal with that.

Comment: I'm not sure we're related... And if it's legacy then perhaps that's only more reason to fix the problem; then it's not a legacy issue anymore.

Comment: Union maybe? But if they create a new one I'll need to change my Procedure again...

Comment: If it's a "legacy" application then why are new databases being added? If it's legacy, then little to nothing should be changing.

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to get all together though.

Comment: You *could* create a `VIEW` that `UNION ALL`s the tables. If you need to do this for many tables, you'll need to create many `VIEW`s. It'll likely be *awful* for performance, but at least you only have to do it once (for each table). This, of course, assumes that you won't be adding new databases, but as it's a legacy application, then that means you won't be (If you are, that suggests it's not a legacy application, and so you should be fixing the design).

Comment: hahahahaha..... They will add new databases. Trust me.... I swear that's not my fault. I'm the freelancer trying to do things right, or at least fix them.

Comment: Then, as a mentioned, fix the design. If those databases need to be queried as "one database" *make them* one database.

Comment: Deal with that:
BaseA -> Select ClientName From Clients Where ClientId = 1 == McDonald's
BaseB -> Select ClientName From Clients Where ClientId = 1 == BurguerKing

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.Clients ADD BaseName sysname; UPDATE dbo.Clients SET BaseName = N'BaseA'; INSERT INTO dbo.Clients ({ColumnList}) SELECT ({Columns}), N'BaseB' FROM Base2.dbo.Clients; ... SELECT ... FROM dbo.JoinedClients JC JOIN dbo.Clients C ON JC.BaseName = C.BaseName;` "Dealt with". As you can see, the query is simple once the design is fixed.

Comment: @ElekGuidolin the only way I see it would solve it is by creating a view and procedure with a dynamic sql, and setup a trigger on create database. Where you will get the new database name, and update view with that database. OR handle it outside the sql server (perhaps a background service on the server).

Answer (score -1):

I hope I've helped.
Below is an example:

```
USE ANY_DATABASE
GO
CREATE DATABASE BaseA;
GO
CREATE DATABASE BaseB;
GO
CREATE TABLE BaseA.dbo.Clients (ClientId INT, ClientName VARCHAR(100))
GO
INSERT INTO BaseA.dbo.Clients (ClientId, ClientName) VALUES (1, 'McDonalds')
GO
CREATE TABLE BaseB.dbo.Clients (ClientId INT, ClientName VARCHAR(100))
GO
INSERT INTO BaseB.dbo.Clients (ClientId, ClientName) VALUES (1, 'Burger King')
GO
DECLARE @database sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @database = 'BaseA'
SET @sql = 'SELECT ClientId, ClientName FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@database) + '.dbo.Clients'
EXEC (@sql)

SET @database = 'BaseB'
SET @sql = 'SELECT ClientId, ClientName FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@database) + '.dbo.Clients'
EXEC (@sql)
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.pr_multdatabase_all_clients') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.pr_multdatabase_all_clients
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pr_multdatabase_all_clients
@database sysname
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ClientId, ClientName FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@database) + '.dbo.Clients'
    EXEC (@sql)
END
GO
EXEC dbo.pr_multdatabase_all_clients @database = 'BaseA'
GO
EXEC dbo.pr_multdatabase_all_clients @database = 'BaseB'
GO
```

Comment: What do you suppose will happen when someone runs `CREATE TABLE #t (ClientID int, ClientName int); EXEC dbo.pr_multdatabase_all_clients N'#t; CREATE LOGIN a WITH PASSWORD = 'a', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; --'; EXEC dbo.pr_multdatabase_all_clients N'#t; ALTER SERVER ROLE sa ADD MEMBER a;--';`? This answer is **dangerous** and should not be used.

Comment: This is just an example that I did here, the correct thing is not to run this script in the master database, do it in another database other than the system ones.

Comment: Not running it in `master` won't save you from the problem of the above being a *huge* injection vulnerability. Only validating the parameters and *properly* quoting and escaping the value(s) will solve that.

Comment: I changed the **database name in the script** for everyone's happiness.

Comment: This is still wide open to injection though....

Comment: Demonstration of injection using this solution: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad2d91547434673fc52f0137abeb93ae)

Comment: Pay attention to the scenario described, I posted a script to help get to the solution, I didn't post the solution.

Comment: Just thinking.... If you can inject sql into parameter, so all parameters are vulnerable?
If not, the very simplest solution is just don't declare :
DECLARE 'At"database sysname;
Declare as string:
DECLARE "At"database varchar(100);
Am I wrong?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).